# C Struct-Function Pointer-Passing Self Reference As Argument

Tags: c, struct, arguments, function-pointers, self-reference

I would like to run the function pointed by my struct with auto-filling functionality.

This is the part that I'm working on:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Fra { //Fraction
  int n;     //Numerator
  int d;     //Denominator
  void (*p)(struct Fra*);
  void (*sD)(int, struct Fra*);
  void (*sN)(int, struct Fra*);
};

void print(struct Fra*);
void setDenom(int, struct Fra*);
void setNum(int, struct Fra*);

int main() {

  struct Fra* fraA = 0;

  fraA = (struct Fra*) malloc(sizeof(struct Fra));

  fraA->sN = setNum;
  fraA->sN(2, fraA);
  fraA->sD = setDenom;
  fraA->sD(3, fraA);
  fraA->p = print;
  fraA->p(fraA);

  return 0;
}
```

And this is what I've been trying to achieve

From:

```
fraA->sN(2, fraA);
fraA->sD(3, fraA);
fraA->p(fraA);
```

To:

```
fraA->sN(2);
fraA->sD(3);
fraA->p();
```

After spending some time on trial-error, I've arrived to the conclusion that I need assistance on this. I've tried browsing, but it seems I don't have the right keyword, so I'm unable to verify whether this question is a double or not.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The simple and only answer to this is that it's not possible in C.

Comment: That statement is very hard to swallow..., but thanks for letting me know. I guess I couldn't cut this particular corner out.

Comment: C++ has classes, which make your desired syntax easily possible. Plus, all a class is, is syntax sugar for a C struct with functions that take a pointer to it. I.e. with a class, `fraA->print(fraA)` becomes `fraA->print()`. I'll post a comparison soon.

Comment: [Here it is](http://pastebin.com/K1DSevTn)! I hope you find it informative.

Answer (score 2):

You could declare some macros to savely always pass the correct reference, that's all you can do:

```
#define FRA_NEW(this, sN sD, sP) \
{ \
  (this) = calloc(sizeof(*(this))) \
  if (this) \
  { \
    (this)->sN = (sN); \
    (this)->sN = (sD); \
    (this)->sN = (sP); \
  } \
}

#define FR_DELETE(this) \
  free(this)

#define FRA_PRINT(this) \
  (this)->print(this)

#define FRA_SETNUM(this, num) \
  (this)->setNum(this, num)

#define FRA_SETDENOM(this, denom) \
  (this)->setDenom(this, denom)
```

Also I'd propose to have "this" always as first parameter to the "member"-functions.

```
int main(void) 
{
  struct Fra * fraA = NULL;

  FRA_NEW(fraA, setNum, setDenom, print);
  if (NULL == fraA)
  {
    perror("FRA_NEW() failed");
    return 1;
  }

  FRA_SETNUM(fraA, 2);
  FRA_SETDENOM(fraA, 3);
  FRA_PRINT(fraA);

  FRA_DELETE(fraA);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the macro naming input. I originally placed 'this' as the first argument, but then since I was thinking of initiating default value, I set 'this' as last argument, haha. But since I realized that I tried to do is impossible in C. I've gone back to my original structure with 'this' as first argument. Alright, thanks again, alk.

Comment: Wouldn't `FRA_PRINT(fraA)` be exactly the same thing as `print(fraA)`, except more work?

Comment: @B1KMusic: Only if the `struct Fra`'s member `print` had been indeed initialised to (and not changed during run-time) to point to `print()`.

Comment: Then having a function pointer in a struct for that purpose would be rendered meaningless, correct? A better option would be to "namespace" the functions (`fra_<function_name>(){...}` instead of `<function_name>(){...}`), or to just use C++ for its `class` datatype, which, IIRC, has a `self` keyword specially made for exactly that purpose. Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: It's not meaningless if you want to either create a sort of generic data-type  (configured on initialisation) or change the functoin-pointers(s) value(s) *during run-time*. @B1KMusic

Comment: Yup, that's why I said "for that purpose". I understand that some libraries/programs would allow the programmer to insert a "custom" function. Like `libpthread`, for instance. I'm merely talking about trying to use C as an OOP language.

Comment: Everything is OOP ... ;-) @B1KMusic

Answer (score 1):

The only really useful way I can think of would be to provide functions which do the job:

```
void call_print(struct Fra* fra)
{
    fra->p(fra);
}

void call_setDenom(int val, struct Fra* fra)
{
    fra->sD(val, fra);
}

void call_setNum(int val, struct Fra* fra);
{
    fra->sN(val, fra);
}
```

and use these:

```
call_setNum(2, fraA);
call_setDenom(3, fraA);
call_print(fraA);
```

Comment: How is `call_print(fraA)` different from simply `print(fraA)`. All that extra effort to do something totally useless.

Comment: @B1KMusic If you don't know (or want to remain flexible about) where `fra->p` points to, the way of going like this is useful to encapsulate the beed for accessing `fra` twice.

Comment: Yeah, sure. It's useful to be able to set a function during runtime if you're making a library (or in dwm's case, for configuration). With this context though, it is useless. What is useless is trying to use C as an OOP. Askers's problem would easily be solved with a C++ class, where instances have a built in pointer to themselves in-scope, and you get syntax sugar like the desired `fraA->print()`.

Comment: "What is useless is trying to use C as an OOP." IBTD. That's absolutely not useless, but a valid approach.

Comment: context, convention and circumstance. Function pointers aren't useless, but `fraA->print (fraA)` is. That's unnecessary data duplication where `print(fraA)` would serve the purpose just as well. Or to put it a nicer way, If you need classes, then use classes.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example that works for me:

```
typedef struct _log_t
{
    log_level_t threshold;
    void (*logger)(struct _log_t*, log_level_t, char *, ...);
} 
log_t;
```